# Rest api jqgrid

Tags: javascript, rest, jqgrid, tinydb

I have a working model of jqgrid loaded data from rest api 'get' method. I have to update the data of the grid. Can anyone help me how to post,put,delete the data through javascript.`

How to write a server side code for rest api python to insert data in TinyDB, and Is my javascript correct?

Comment: so what do u want ? python api side code or js code ?